# I want my novel to contain custom fonts - what should I do?

Tags: publishing, novel

I intend to write an extensive fantasy series. There is a plethora of different languages and cultures in the series, and I've developed language systems and alphabets for some of those cultures, including unique lettering. It is possible that at some point in the series, I would like to include samples of those letters.

**What should I do to achieve this?** Should I learn a font-creation software and make them myself? Should I hire a professional? Does the publisher take care of the whole thing? What's the best option, *in terms of getting it done right* (as opposed to just the easiest way to get away with it)?

Note: I do want a custom *font*, which I can safely and legally use on my own fan-site if I so wished. Not just the letters used in the novels, the whole alphabet.

Comment: So not fonts so much as an entirely new language?

Comment: I know my comment won't be on point, but just wanted to say tat one of the few books I bought  and never got past the first chapter, had pages of dialogue in an original "language" .  The story was supposedly very good, but I never got to find out. Still consider it one of the most infuriating and frustrating things I ever tried to read.

Comment: Be careful that your languages and fonts don't get in the way of the story. Not many readers will examine words and lettering that they can't understand; most are likely to skip that stuff and look for where the story picks up again. ("Try to leave out the part that readers tend to skip." -- Elmore Leonard)

Comment: Don't worry, I know story comes first. I simply want the *ability* to use the fonts if the the need should arise. And I will *not* be writing whole dialogues with them or anything. Think more like LotR, with Gandalf's symbol being a Dwarvish and Elvish rune.

Comment: @Thomo No... I have the language. What I need is the font.

Comment: @ThomasMyron I have been looking into this for something similar with myself. I know there are free lance people you can hire to create fonts for you and a language. I saw a site that does all of that for just 300 bucks. You may want to consider looking into options for just the scripted writing which I believe they provide.

Comment: @ggiaquin What about the legal side of things? Do they own it or do I?

Comment: http://jobs.conlang.org/about Is their site linking to the job boards. They have a full site outside of that as well. It's been a while since I browsed this since I wanted to wait until I got my story written to see if it was actually worth the investment or not. It is my understanding though that most of them will only ask for a shout out in the front matters and that you control the work they provide for you (since what they do is based off of your IP anyways). They are also already compensated when you pay for their services. https://conlang.org/ is their regular society site.

Comment: I am an artist, I would love to see what you had in mind for your fonts. I may be able to make them a reality. (:

Comment: @AspenRand With no copyright loopholes anyone could exploit? If so, you sir are hired. I just have to make sure this is completely air tight.

Comment: @AspenRand Do you have any previous work I can look at/website/way to contact you?

Comment: Yes, I have an e-mail where we can speak.  it's   aspen.otaku@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a font editor/creator software.

I installed one not too long ago on my own laptop because I wanted a more cursive look to parts of some of my chapters (for when someone is reading or writing a letter kind of thing).

You can create a complete "alphabet" with that, with as many squiggles and funny symbols has you might or might not need.

Font Forge  https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/ is a free/open source software. And... there are tutorials for it as well.

Comment: What about the legal side of things though? Am I free to use it however I wish? Will the publisher use it at all?

Comment: Font Forge allows you to create your own fonts. You just draw them as you see fit, they are yours, your creation. Wether the publisher uses them, is up to you and the publisher.

Comment: Sorry, tablet not cooperating https://fontforge.github.io/editexample.html